# I am getting a null pointee exception when i select a spinner

Tags: android, json, spinner

I am getting a null pointer exception when i click my spinner which passes json object into the next activity.

Here is my spinner code

```
retrieveGames1BGTask = new RetrieveGames1BGTask();
        retrieveGames1BGTask.execute();
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = null;
                    switch (position) {
                        case 1:
                            intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Basketball.class);
                            i.putExtra("json_data2", retrieveGames1BGTask.getResult());
                            startActivity(intent);
                            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),
                                    parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString() + " View Selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                    }
                }
```

In my next activity i have this line of code

```
if (intent != null) {

            json_string1 = intent.getStringExtra("json_data2");
        }
```

The logcat says this

```
   java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                at com.example.aaa.bbb.Games$1.onItemSelected(Games.java:216)
 at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:964) at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:928)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Your logcat seems to show obfuscated code. Please disable obfuscation and repost.

What code line is logcat pointing to when it says "at com.examaple...onItemSelected(Games.java:xxx)"?

Games.java is the activity that has the spinner code? I suggest you use more complete names like GameActivity.java and BasketballActivity.java so we can understand your code better.

Notice you request getContext() twice from two different sources (view and parent). If you're in an activity anyway, just use Game.this.

Comment: How to i disable it sir?

Comment: minifyEnabled false in your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to bind to the list possibly before the task has finished. There is no guarantee that retrieveGames1BGTask will be done before you bind. This is why you should override the onPostExecute method in your AsyncTask to ensure you bind to your spinner after the completion of your background task.

Comment: I did not use asynctask in populating my data in my spinner sir.

Comment: Sorry, i meant in putting it as an extra for your intent